# How to send CONTROL+C at spawn in nodejs

Tags: windows, node.js, cmd

I run CMD to spawn, but if you'll send me a ping command, I can not get out of it, how can I send the console control + c, to avoid this? THANKS!

```
var fs = require('fs');
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
function sendData (msg) {
    console.log('write msg ', msg);
    cmd.stdin.write(msg + "\r\n");
}
function execCommand() {
    console.log('start command line')
    var s = { 
        e : 'exec_command',
        d : {
          data : {}
        }
    };
    cmd = require('child_process').spawn('cmd', ['/K']);

    cmd.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(iconv.decode(data, 'cp866'));
    });

}

execCommand();
sendData('ping e1.ru -t');
sendData( EXIT ??? )
```

---

?????
I want to make a console, a full-fledged console through node.js.

```
sendData('dir');
sendData('cd /d Windows');
sendData('ping 8.8.8.8 -t');
senData( CONTROL + C );
senData('dir')
```

Comment: alternate solution: use ```ping e1.ru -c 5``` to ping the host 5 times.

Comment: nonono! only ping -t...

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to explicitly call:

```
cmd.kill();
```

that'll do the trick. If you require the equivalent of `CTRL-C` then call:

```
cmd.kill('SIGINT');
```

See [child_process.kill](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal) docs for more info.

Comment: NO KILL PROCESS! I HAVE TO MAKE A STOP PING, NO KILL SPAWN.

Comment: Are you expecting to send more commands through the child process?

Comment: This is not completely exact. If the process did a `stdin` redirection, like `std:cin` and `std::cout << " " << data;`, that keeps the `stdin` open, sending a `child.kill('SIGINT')`will not work. NOTE. The `child.stdin.write('"\x03")` will not work as well.