# How to send control C node.js and child_processes

Tags: windows, node.js, child-process

Hello I want to send to the child_process, for example, ping 8.8.8.8-t, that is, an infinite number of ping. And some of the iterations I want to stop this command and execute a new, but in this case I do not want to kill a child process.

Example:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn('cmd'),
    iconv = require('iconv-lite');

spawn.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('Stdout: ', iconv.decode(data, 'cp866'));
});

spawn.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('Stderr: ', iconv.decode(data, 'cp866'));
});

spawn.stdin.write('ping 8.8.8.8 -t'+ '\r\n');

spawn.stdin.write(here control-c...); // WRONG

spawn.stdin.write('dir' + '\r\n');
```

Answer (score 4):

I found your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16332003/how-to-send-controlc-at-spawn-in-nodejs). Looks like you are trying to create/emulate a terminal from within node.js. You can use [readline](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) for reading and writing from a terminal.

To write control character, you can see the example from its [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_write_data_key) :

```
  rl.write('Delete me!');
  // Simulate ctrl+u to delete the line written previously
  rl.write(null, {ctrl: true, name: 'u'});
```

To directly answer the question, to pass special characters you will need to pass their ASCII values. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> becomes ASCII character 0x03. Value taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters).

```
  spawn.stdin.write("\x03");
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not really understand how I use it as a terminal and send, such as ping. Maybe tell me? spawn.stdin.write("\x03") - not working :(

Comment: Not working for me as well, even setting `ascii` mode `self.child.stdin.setEncoding('ascii'); self.child.stdin.write("\x03");//CTRL-C`